# pipes and fork with Control.Concurrent.MonadIO

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-pipes

In the following code I am trying to combine 2 `Producer`s into 1. All have the same type. They will be combined by each of the 2 input `Producer`s being run in a separate thread and being consumed by a `Consumer` that puts the values into an unagi chan (I'm using unagi chan for performance). A producer is returned which reads from the chan. I want to be able to take any `Producer` as long as it can run `IO` so I restrict the class of the monad to `MonadIO` and `HasFork`.

```
import Pipes (Producer, Consumer, (>->), yield, await, runEffect)
import Control.Concurrent.Chan.Unagi (InChan, OutChan, newChan, readChan, writeChan)
import Control.Monad (forever, void)
import Control.Concurrent.MonadIO (MonadIO, HasFork, liftIO, fork)

combine :: (MonadIO m, HasFork m) => Producer a m r -> Producer a m r -> Producer a m r
combine p1 p2 = do
  (inChan, outChan) <- liftIO $ newChan
  t1 <- fork . void . runEffect $ p1 >-> (consumer inChan)
  t2 <- fork . void . runEffect $ p2 >-> (consumer inChan)
  producer outChan

producer :: (MonadIO m) => OutChan a -> Producer a m r
producer outChan = forever $ do
  msg <- liftIO $ readChan outChan
  yield msg

consumer :: (MonadIO m) => InChan a -> Consumer a m r
consumer inChan = forever $ do
  msg <- await
  liftIO $ writeChan inChan msg
```

However I get the following error:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’
                 with ‘Pipes.Internal.Proxy Pipes.Internal.X () () a m’
  ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      combine :: forall (m :: * -> *) a r.
                 (MonadIO m, HasFork m) =>
                 Producer a m r -> Producer a m r -> Producer a m r
    at src/Pipes/Unagi.hs:8:12
  Expected type: Pipes.Internal.Proxy
                   Pipes.Internal.X () () a m GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId
    Actual type: m GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Add `lift` in front of `fork`. `fork stuff :: m ThreadId`, `lift :: m r -> Producer a m r`. Although I don't think there are a lot of interesting types that you can actually fork.

Comment: Sweet it worked. Can you explain why it works? Maybe you should post an answer so I can mark it as correct and you get more points?

Comment: Also, the reason I want to use `fork` is so that I can use any monad stack as long as it has IO. It doesn't matter that `IO` is about the only type you can `fork`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `lift` in front of `fork`.

```
t1 <- lift . fork . ...
```

In your function, `fork . ...` has type `m ThreadId`, but the `do` block is in the monad `Producer a m`.

Also, `lifted-base` has a more up to date `fork`.

Comment: Ah yes, originally I tried to do this with lifted-async but I couldn't work it out. I couldn't find any information on how I 'run' a `MonadBase`. Or how do I run `(MonadIO m, MonadBase m) => Producer a m r`?

Comment: `MonadBaseControl IO m` is just like `HasFork m`. There is no "run" function to apply.